# Done column -- use case?

Tags: scrum, kanban

Seems to be ubiquitous...the "done" or "completed" column. Conceptually what purposes does it serve? Is it the feel good reminder that "hey we've accomplished X number of tasks/stories"

I struggle with using valuable screen space or physical whiteboard for such a thing, when electronically I can pull those tasks up at any time.

Perhaps in Scrum, with it's iterations, the "done" column is handy for showing team/stakeholders/collaborators whats been done and what needs to be done and what is being done.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Where are you seeing a superfluous "done" column?

Comment: I didn't say superfluous I say ubiquitous :) Google kanban or scrum boards and view images...almost every single one has "done" columns...why? What purpose does it serve? Is it strictly a visual reminder to teams of progress made? To me it implies it can be "undone" -- perhaps my thinking is off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's necessary to communicate when a card is ... done. Without it, for example, it would be impossible to take a list of what was done recently and review it.

It's often a final state. On our board, "done" stories are reviewed and removed every Monday, when we prepare our "what we did last week" report.

Comment: Thats what I needed to hear someone confirm...after X number of iterations or days or whatever a team decides on...the "done" gets reset/cleared.